# Authentication changes in .NET 4.5.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have some knowledge on **.NET 4.5**, but totally new to **4.5.1**. As I read, they have a couple of changes so that apps work with `Identity`, which is nice for scale web apps.

That being said, I need to work on a web app with a basic user/password login system and I'm wondering if this template `Individual User Accounts` can work, or if I have to go with `No Authentication`? Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> basic user/password login system

**Individual User Accounts** will configure **ASP.Net Identity** for you. In addition, it will also create basic login, logout and other extra templates too. Click on [Learn more](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#auth) for more information.

[image]

However, if you just need simple **FormAuthentication**, you want to select **No Authentication**.

The following is the example of simple **FormAuthentication**.

### Sign-In method

```
public void SignIn(string username, bool createPersistentCookie)
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
    TimeSpan expirationTimeSpan = FormsAuthentication.Timeout;

    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1 /*version*/,
        username,
        now,
        now.Add(expirationTimeSpan),
        createPersistentCookie,
        "" /*userData*/,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
        encryptedTicket)
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
    };

    if (ticket.IsPersistent)
    {
        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    }
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
    {
        cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
    }

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

### Global.asax.cs

You need this in order to retrieve the username from cookie, and save it in IPrincipal Object.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie decryptedCookie =
            Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
            FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(decryptedCookie.Value);

        var identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
}
```

### web.config

Make sure you have authentication tag in web.config.

For example,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
</authentication>
```

### Usage

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var username = User.Identity.Name;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Doesnt the login server control do all that automatically for you? It definently creates a cookie etc. Might be an idea if you just want the basics?

Comment: @MrCharli3 Good question; it is true in ASP.Net Web Form. ASP.Net MVC doesn't have login control.