# Redirect to login-page when user is not logged in (asp)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, redirect, authentication

I have a login-page where users can log in.
When they logging in with correctly details they are sent to an main admin-page.
If they cant log in they are staying on the login-page.
What I want to do is, if a random user, type in the URL for an admin-page when they are not logged in they are redirecting to the login-page.

I have understood that I have to do it in the masterpage or webconfig!?! I have a main admin-page and some other admin-pages.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net has [ASP.Net Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) which basically is membership system.

It'll be over kill for a simple website with couple of pages. If you just want a very basic feature without overhead, you could just look at -

- [Claim Based Authentication with OWIN Cookie Middleware](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/OwinAuthenticationService.cs#L20)
- [Form Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334010/296861)

Comment: I tried to insert this into my webconfig:
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="InnUtlogging.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
  </authentication>

here is my code for the "login"-button;

Comment: thanks, here is the link for the new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119193/authentication-mode-forms-doesnt-work

Comment: If this answer solves the original question, please mark it as *Answer*. It'll help the community.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to insert this into my webconfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="InnUtlogging.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
  </authentication>
```

here is my code for the "login"-button (on the login-page);

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * FROM Ansatt WHERE epost='" + brukernavn.Text + "' and passord='" + passord.Text + "'");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        int OBJ = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (OBJ > 0)

            {
            Session["name"] = brukernavn.Text;
            Response.Redirect("KunstnerAdmin.aspx");
        }
        else
            {
                melding.Text = "Feil brukernavn/passord";
            }
        if (brukernavn.Text == "")
        {
            melding.Text = "Du må fylle inn brukernavn";

        }
        if (passord.Text == "")
        {
            melding.Text = "Du må fylle inn passord";
        }
        }
```

But actually I want to check if user is logged in in the master-page.
Is there something I can do in the masterpage to activate the forms authentication?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not ask new question in answer area.